# Recording video by Js Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capture video by recordrtc.js but I get this problem solving the promise:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source Promise.then (async)
(anonymous);

[image]

it happens in chrome and firefox but in edge and explorer works perfectly.

Thanks for your help

```js
    let permission = document.querySelector("#start");
    
    permission.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var camera_permission = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video:true,
            audio: false
        }).then((stream)=>{
          if(stream.active == true){
            console.log("la camara esta activa")
          }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code to the following you can at least see more about which error you are getting:

```js
    let permission = document.querySelector("#start");

    permission.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var camera_permission = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video:true,
            audio: false
        }).then((stream)=>{
          if(stream.active == true){
            console.log("la camara esta activa")
          }
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

What to do next depends on what kind of error you are getting. You can read about the different possible errors in the [exceptions section of this page.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)